# Python 3.X or Python 2.7 in Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed Anaconda on Windows 7 from the full installer and then created an Anaconda Python 3 environment (py3k) using conda. From my reading of the installation instructions at

http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3

I type activate py3k at the Anaconda command prompt to obtain that environment and in the  Command Prompt window it says

[py3k] C:\users.. etc

which would appear to indicate that I am, in fact, in a Python 3.X environment. However, when I type 'Python' at the prompt I get

Python 2.7.5 | Anaconda ... etc

Am I still in a Python 3.X environment or have I omitted to do something installation-wise or otherwise?

Comment: have you tried running `python3` instead of `python`?

Comment: If I try that I just get the standard:

Comment: Python3 is not recognised as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `unset PYTHONPATH`, and `which python`?

If you do that after activating py3, you should be able to the python 3 interpreter. If not, what do you get after executing `which python`?